# Date and age validation with jquery validation in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

In my first steps in ASP.NET Core MVC; I am trying to perform a validation of the date of birth field with jQuery validation since the data annotations does not allow it or I do not know how to do it.

The validation consists in the first part of the user selecting a different date to today's date and at least select a date 5 years ago to later validate the age based on the date by performing a calculation, as seen in the image is what I would like to do, the question is how to do it based on the code that I maintain.

[image]

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#formPaciente').validate({
            rules: {
                txtFecNac: "required",
                txtEdad: {
                    required: true,
                    Range:[5,90]
                }
            },
            messages: {
                txtFecNac: "La Fecha Nacimiento es requerida",
                txtEdad: {
                    required: "Su edad es requerida",
                    Range: "La edad debe ser entre 5 y 90"
                }
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

But my qiestions are like first how to calculate the age based on the date of birth using jQuery validation and second is to be able to validate that the date of birth at least based on the calculation of the age I am 5 years old with which I would fill a additional field called representative and if it is greater then I normally continue with the next field, which would be the correct way to carry out this validation.

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this attribute to the date input `max=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Just like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="birthday" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="birthday" class="form-control" max=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")/>
            <span asp-validation-for="birthday" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

And the result looks like below, no need to validate again.

[image]

And to calculate the age, just add an Onchange event for the date input and according to the birth date user clicked, update the age input.

```
$("#tarDate").on("change", function () {
        var now = new Date();
        var birthdate = new Date($("#tarDate").val());
        var nowyear = now.getFullYear();
        var birthyear = birthdate.getFullYear();
        var age = nowyear - birthyear + 1;
        $('#age').val(age);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the answer in the English community, because in Spanish I was not successful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and mark. I'm really glad to see you've solved your issue : )

Answer (score 2):

This is the code of my registration form for my patient where I put the id to be used later in the script to validate what the client asks me.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
    <input id="FecNacVal" asp-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_FECHA_NAC" type="date" placeholder="FECHA NAC." class="form-control" max=@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") />
    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_FECHA_NAC" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Edad Paciente:</label>
    <input id="EdadVal" asp-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_EDAD" type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="EDAD" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_EDAD" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>Representante:</label>
    <input id="RepPacVal" asp-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_REPRESENTANTE" type="text" disabled placeholder="REPRESENTANTE" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_REPRESENTANTE" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I put the code that is finally in the script

```
    @section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#FecNacVal").on("change", function () {
                var now = new Date();
                var birthdate = new Date($("#FecNacVal").val()); // Se Procede a calcular en base a la fecha
                var nowyear = now.getFullYear();
                var birthyear = birthdate.getFullYear();
                var age = nowyear - birthyear + 1;
                $('#EdadVal').val(age);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#FecNacVal").on("change", function () {
                // Accedemos al botón
                var RepresentanteValidacion = document.getElementById('RepPacVal');
                var EdadValidacion = $("#EdadVal").val(); // Obtenemos el Valor del campo Edad
                //console.log(EdadValidacion);
                if (EdadValidacion >= 18) { // Validamos si es mayor o menor
                    // evento para el input Deshabilitado
                    // console.log("Mayor de edad");
                    RepresentanteValidacion.disabled = true; // Deshabilitado
                }
                else if (EdadValidacion < 18) {
                    //console.log("Menor de edad");
                    // evento para el input Habilitar
                    RepresentanteValidacion.disabled = false; // Habilitado
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial">

}
```